# Asynchronous view manipulation android

Tags: android, multithreading, model-view-controller, asynchronous

I have a little problem I spend a lot of time now. I hope you can help me.
Well, I have an activity witch loads content out of data base in background. It returns asynchrony and modifies my data model. Now I'm looking for a good way to inform the controller to update view. I use the notifyDataChanged method but I got an exception.

Android do not allow to modify a view from another thread. In my opinion this is a basic functionality. So there has to be a way to implement such a functionality.

Can you give me an hint.

I also watch the content observer class. But I don't think that the right one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide some code snippets from your `Activity`. If you are using `AsynkTask` which is the best way to do background processing on data, you should use the `onPostExecute()` method to update your UI, because `doInBackground()` runs on a background thread, not on the UIThread.

A workaround would be to declare a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your `Activity` and post a new `Runnable` in that `Handler` when you want to acccess the UI, something like this:

```
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

But this is somehow a "hack" and I wouldn't recommend using this. The best way would be to use the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: This can trigger IllegalStateException{}, you need to runOnUIThread()